# Spring Boot 2.3 + GraalVM Error encountered while parsing config

Tags: spring, spring-boot, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I have a spring boot 2.3 app which I want to compile as a native image.

I'm using GraalVM `20.1.0.r11-grl` as the SDK/JDK and my application compiles and runs fine.
I'm using Gradle for my build tool, and am using https://github.com/ayltai/spring-graalvm-native-plugin to access Native Image functionality - it works well.

When I try to compile a native image, I get the following stack trace (the original is about 900 lines long in verbose mode so I'm trying to pick out the relevant bits):

```
WARNING: Could not register reflection metadata for org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.web.reactive.WebFluxEndpointManagementContextConfiguration. Reason: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/reactive/result/method/annotation/RequestMappingHandlerMapping.
WARNING: Could not register reflection metadata for org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.web.jersey.JerseySameManagementContextConfiguration. Reason: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/glassfish/jersey/server/ResourceConfig.
[valuable-api:14937]     analysis:  53,754.65 ms,  3.98 GB
Fatal error:com.oracle.graal.pointsto.util.AnalysisError$ParsingError: Error encountered while parsing org.springframework.hateoas.config.WebFluxHateoasConfiguration$WebFluxCodecs.getDecoder(com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper, java.util.List) 
Parsing context:
        parsing com.oracle.svm.reflect.WebFluxHateoasConfiguration$WebFluxCodecs_getDecoder_ebe8383216b03b797b6e4dde145c81aea1634443_11905.invoke(Unknown Source)
        parsing java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        parsing org.springframework.core.convert.support.ObjectToObjectConverter.convert(ObjectToObjectConverter.java:102)
        parsing org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionUtils.invokeConverter(ConversionUtils.java:41)
        parsing org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:191)
        parsing org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:174)
        parsing org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.convertValueIfNecessary(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:265)
        parsing org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:91)
        parsing org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:62)
        parsing org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.getProperty(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:169)
        parsing org.springframework.core.env.AbstractEnvironment.getProperty(AbstractEnvironment.java:540)
        parsing org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationBannerPrinter.createStringFromBanner(SpringApplicationBannerPrinter.java:116)
        parsing org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationBannerPrinter.print(SpringApplicationBannerPrinter.java:61)
        parsing org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.printBanner(SpringApplication.java:556)
        parsing org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310)
        parsing org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237)
        parsing org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
        parsing nz.ringfence.valuable.api.ValuableApiApplication.main(ValuableApiApplication.java:11)
        parsing com.oracle.svm.core.JavaMainWrapper.runCore(JavaMainWrapper.java:149)
        parsing com.oracle.svm.core.JavaMainWrapper.run(JavaMainWrapper.java:184)
        parsing com.oracle.svm.core.code.IsolateEnterStub.JavaMainWrapper_run_5087f5482cc9a6abc971913ece43acb471d2631b(generated:0)

        at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.util.AnalysisError.parsingError(AnalysisError.java:138)
        at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.MethodTypeFlow.doParse(MethodTypeFlow.java:336)
        at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.MethodTypeFlow.ensureParsed(MethodTypeFlow.java:311)
        at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.MethodTypeFlow.addContext(MethodTypeFlow.java:112)
        at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.StaticInvokeTypeFlow.update(InvokeTypeFlow.java:437)
        at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.BigBang$2.run(BigBang.java:530)
        at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.util.CompletionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(CompletionExecutor.java:173)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1426)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:177)
Caused by: org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser$BytecodeParserError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/reactivestreams/Publisher
        at parsing org.springframework.hateoas.config.WebFluxHateoasConfiguration$WebFluxCodecs.getDecoder(WebFluxHateoasConfiguration.java:123)
        at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.throwParserError(BytecodeParser.java:2590)
        at com.oracle.svm.hosted.phases.SharedGraphBuilderPhase$SharedBytecodeParser.throwParserError(SharedGraphBuilderPhase.java:94)
        at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.iterateBytecodesForBlock(BytecodeParser.java:3428)
        at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.processBlock(BytecodeParser.java:3230)
        at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.build(BytecodeParser.java:1088)
        at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.buildRootMethod(BytecodeParser.java:982)
        at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.GraphBuilderPhase$Instance.run(GraphBuilderPhase.java:84)
        at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.phases.Phase.run(Phase.java:49)
        at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.phases.BasePhase.apply(BasePhase.java:214)
        at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.phases.Phase.apply(Phase.java:42)
        at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.phases.Phase.apply(Phase.java:38)
        at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.MethodTypeFlowBuilder.parse(MethodTypeFlowBuilder.java:225)
        at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.MethodTypeFlowBuilder.apply(MethodTypeFlowBuilder.java:352)
        at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.MethodTypeFlow.doParse(MethodTypeFlow.java:322)
        ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/reactivestreams/Publisher
        at jdk.internal.vm.ci/jdk.vm.ci.hotspot.CompilerToVM.getDeclaredMethods(Native Method)
        at jdk.internal.vm.ci/jdk.vm.ci.hotspot.HotSpotResolvedObjectTypeImpl.getDeclaredMethods(HotSpotResolvedObjectTypeImpl.java:958)
        at com.oracle.svm.hosted.classinitialization.ClassInitializationFeature.declaresDefaultMethods(ClassInitializationFeature.java:385)
        at com.oracle.svm.hosted.classinitialization.ConfigurableClassInitialization.processInterfaces(ConfigurableClassInitialization.java:606)
        at com.oracle.svm.hosted.classinitialization.ConfigurableClassInitialization.computeInitKindAndMaybeInitializeClass(ConfigurableClassInitialization.java:565)
        at com.oracle.svm.hosted.classinitialization.ConfigurableClassInitialization.computeInitKindAndMaybeInitializeClass(ConfigurableClassInitialization.java:132)
        at com.oracle.svm.hosted.classinitialization.ConfigurableClassInitialization.maybeInitializeHosted(ConfigurableClassInitialization.java:160)
        at com.oracle.svm.hosted.SVMHost.registerType(SVMHost.java:223)
        at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.meta.AnalysisUniverse.createType(AnalysisUniverse.java:264)
        at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.meta.AnalysisUniverse.lookupAllowUnresolved(AnalysisUniverse.java:205)
        at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.meta.AnalysisUniverse.lookup(AnalysisUniverse.java:182)
        at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.meta.AnalysisType.convertTypes(AnalysisType.java:209)
        at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.meta.AnalysisType.<init>(AnalysisType.java:169)
        at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.meta.AnalysisUniverse.createType(AnalysisUniverse.java:263)
        at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.meta.AnalysisUniverse.lookupAllowUnresolved(AnalysisUniverse.java:205)
        at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.meta.AnalysisUniverse.lookup(AnalysisUniverse.java:182)
        at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.meta.AnalysisType.<init>(AnalysisType.java:168)
        at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.meta.AnalysisUniverse.createType(AnalysisUniverse.java:263)
        at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.meta.AnalysisUniverse.lookupAllowUnresolved(AnalysisUniverse.java:205)
        at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.infrastructure.WrappedConstantPool.lookupType(WrappedConstantPool.java:155)
        at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.lookupType(BytecodeParser.java:4274)
        at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.genNewInstance(BytecodeParser.java:4545)
        at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.processBytecode(BytecodeParser.java:5343)
        at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.iterateBytecodesForBlock(BytecodeParser.java:3423)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.reactivestreams.Publisher
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        ... 46 more
Error: Image build request failed with exit status 1
com.oracle.svm.driver.NativeImage$NativeImageError: Image build request failed with exit status 1
        at com.oracle.svm.driver.NativeImage.showError(NativeImage.java:1541)
        at com.oracle.svm.driver.NativeImage.build(NativeImage.java:1299)
        at com.oracle.svm.driver.NativeImage.performBuild(NativeImage.java:1260)
        at com.oracle.svm.driver.NativeImage.main(NativeImage.java:1219)
        at com.oracle.svm.driver.NativeImage$JDK9Plus.main(NativeImage.java:1722)
```

So this error appears to be happening because Native Image thinks I have a WebFlux component on my classpath, and when it tried to process that component, it can't find it, hence the `ClassNotFoundException` at the bottom of the trace.

Here are my dependencies:

```
// Spring Boot
implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
implementation('org.springframework.hateoas:spring-hateoas:1.1.1.RELEASE')
implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop')
implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation')
runtimeOnly('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
annotationProcessor "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor"

// Native Image
implementation('org.springframework:spring-context-indexer')
implementation('org.springframework.experimental:spring-graalvm-native:0.7.1')

// Testing
testImplementation('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.3.1')
testRuntimeOnly('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.3.1')
testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
testImplementation("org.assertj:assertj-core:3.12.0")
testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.+'
testImplementation "org.springframework.security:spring-security-test"
testImplementation 'com.intuit.karate:karate-junit5:0.9.5'
testImplementation 'com.intuit.karate:karate-apache:0.9.5'
testImplementation "net.masterthought:cucumber-reporting:3.8.0"

// Persistence
implementation('com.h2database:h2')
implementation('org.postgresql:postgresql')
implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc')
implementation "org.flywaydb:flyway-core"

// Swagger
implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.3.0'

// Observability
implementation 'io.sentry:sentry-spring:1.7.30'
implementation 'io.honeycomb.beeline:beeline-spring-boot-starter:1.2.0'
implementation 'nl.basjes.parse.useragent:yauaa:5.18'

// Security
implementation 'com.auth0:auth0-spring-security-api:1.3.1'
implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-resource-server'
implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-jose'
implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-config'

// Outgoing Email
implementation 'com.sendgrid:sendgrid-java:4.0.1'
```

There are no reactive components there. The only thing I can think of is that there is a transitive dependency somewhere, but it doesn't make sense that a non-reactive component would have a transitive dependency?

Has anyone had this issue before? How can I debug and fix this?

Comment: Yeah I heavily got those errors while working on https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2020/05/spring-boot-graalvm/ - there were two "options" then for me: simply trying to use the native-image agent to try to generate the working configuration for the build process - or it simply didn't work right now, since the `spring-graal-native` project didn't support the component I used to this date. As Spring One 2020 happened last week, I'am not sure if `0.7.1` is enough to use `spring-boot-starter-jdbc`, since `JDBC` will be supported from `0.8.x` only.

Comment: Trying to answer your specific question: you don't explicitely rely on a Webflux / `spring-boot-starter-webflux` dependency yourself - but have a look at the stack trace: `Error encountered while parsing org.springframework.hateoas.config.WebFluxHateoasConfiguration$WebFluxCodecs` seems to point us to your dependency `spring-hateoas`. I would suspect, that this dep makes use of the WebFlux classes...

Comment: Additionally I think what you try to do, is to grab a existing "full-blown" Spring Boot app and build it into a native image without much hassle?! I guess that's a hard job right now, since the GraalVM support in Spring is still in it's early stages and considered `alpha` right now. I think you have to options: Strip your app down to the absolute minimum dependencies needed and try to have a look at the spring-graal-native sample projects' configuration on GitHub - or simply wait for the planned December `beta` release of the spring-graal-native (or even wait for around Spring next year).